# How to use MSI for development in visual studio?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I need to get access to my Key Vault during development and debugging. 
Is it possible via using managed service identity?
I see that my code can [get this credentials when the app is deployed on VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-how-to-use-vm-msi-token#get-a-token-using-c), but what if I need them during development on my local workstation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2017 15.8.something, the extension which juunas mentioned is built into Visual Studio.

Tools -> Options -> Azure Service Authentication -> Account Selection

Comment: As a note, if you have also installed az cli and are authenticated, it will use those credentials instead of the ones specified in the UI.

Comment: Sometimes you need to un-set it and re-set it, I was getting auth errors and just remove and reinstated and it all started working.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the docs for the [DefaultAzureCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential) (.NET) which explain how to set this up for both development and Managed Identity.

Below are the links for some of the other supported languages.

[Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential)

[JavaScript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/identity/identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential)

[Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to install the [2.0 Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#install-on-windows), and log in with `az login`. Then make sure the right subscription is selected with `az account set -s "My Azure Subscription name or id"`.

Then you will need to make sure the user account you signed in as has access to the Key Vault.

Now restart Visual Studio, and run the app. It should authenticate successfully.

Another way is to use the new [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension) instead of the CLI.

Comment: I don't understand which code can get a value from Key Vault? Could you add a short sample? Note: I have different accounts in visual studio and in Azure

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Microsoft sample app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/)  ([Github project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet)) with fairly detailed instructions on how to get up and running with local dev using MSI and Key Vault in the readme

The key is that when you are debugging locally you're not running as the service principal of the app registered by MSI, but rather as yourself. The Azure CLI `az login` and `az account set` commands set the default context for your debugging session. You'll run those commands and then log in to the portal with your Azure identity and give your azure identity access to the key vault.