# How to use MSI for development in visual studio code?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-node-sdk

Is it possible to use managed service identity from command line or from Visual Studio Code?
I've seen there's an [extension for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756248/how-to-use-msi-for-development-in-visual-studio). Is there anything similar for VS Code, or an MSI endpoint accessible outside Azure?

If not, what's the correct way of mocking/bypassing MSI authentication?

Than you in advance!

Edit: I'm using nodejs and trying to get the Keyvault working with MSI, following [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-node-quickstart).

Answer (score 1):

You can login to the [AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) using `az login`, the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication library will use that as one of the methods it attempts.

*Unfortunately this approach does not work with the NodeJS library and is being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/2284*

Just ensure you are logged in to the right tenant.

And at least if trying to connect with Azure Key Vault, you also need to select your subscription with `az account set -s "My Azure Subscription name or id"`.

You may need to restart VS Code after logging in in a command prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately, after I login, select the subscription and start my node application, it fails saying `Error: Either provide "msiEndpoint" as a property of the "options" object or set the environment variable "MSI_ENDPOINT" and it must be of type "string".`

Comment: Ah you have a node app :) Based on the error it sounds like it does not support this method.

Comment: Support for using Azure CLI for local development for Node SDK is not supported as of now. It is being tracked here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/2284