# How to get Azure Key Vault to show up under connected services

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to use Azure Key Vault as a connected service in a VS 2017 Web App project.  I am following the tutorial at https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-key-vault-as-a-connected-service-in-visual-studio-2017/ and I have all of the prerequisites shown but Azure Key Vault still does not show-up under available connected services.

I tried downloading the Azure Key Vault Nuget and that did not work.  I installed the web development workload and that did not work.  I changed from .net framework 4.6.1 to 4.7.1 and that did not work.  I am using VS 2017 Community Version 15.9.12.  How can I get the key vault service to show-up?

I would like to be able to use Azure Key Vault as a connected service.

Comment: Why do you need key vault as a connected service ? are you using managed identity in your application ? you can use this approach in VS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52149006/4167200

Comment: I am not yet using managed identity but the method described in the link you sent does not seem too complicated.  However, the method in the tutorial which uses Key Vault as a service is even more simple.  I will give it a try like the link you sent.  Thanks.